Computing Component of Vector Outside Convex Hull of Set of Vectors
I have a set of points $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^N$ where $x_n \in \mathbb{R}^D$. I have another vector $y \in \mathbb{R}^D$. I'd like to efficiently compute the component of $y$ that lives outside the convex hull of the set of points $\{x_n\}_n$.
Is this possible, and if so, what algorithms/methods exists for doing so?
In case it is helpful, in my setting, $N >> D$.
To be clear, I do not want to know whether the vector $y$ is inside or outside the convex hull. I want to compute the component of $y$ outside the convex hull. The result should be a vector, not a Boolean.

What do you mean by the "component of $y$ that lives outside the convex hull"???

Let's say we have 3 points in 2D: (0, 0), (1, 0) and (0, 1), and the vector $y$ is (2, 0). The component of y that lives outside the convex hull defined by the 3 points is the vector (1, 0).

If the vector $y$ is instead (1, 1), then the component of y that lives outside the convex hull defined by the 3 points is the vector ($\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}$)

Maybe here's a different way to phrase the question: Define $y_{proj}$ as point inside the convex hull closest to $y$, as measured by the $L^2$ distance: $y_{proj} := \arg \min_{y' \in hull} ||y' - y||$. What I want is then $y - y_{proj}$.

First find the nearest point $p$ to the hull, then $y-p$ is your "component".

Right, how do I do that first step? Are there efficient algorithms to do this? If so, what are they and how fast or slow are they?

Not sure about the efficiency, but there is a finite algorithm in Wolfe, P., "Finding the Nearest Point in a Polytope," Mathematical Programming 11,
